# Tensor products commute with direct sums

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, tensor-products, direct-sum

I am trying to show that tensor products and directs sums commute, i.e.
$$
M \otimes \left( \bigoplus_{i \in I} N_i \right) \simeq \bigoplus_{i \in I} (M \otimes N_i).
$$

I tried to consider the well-defined homomorphism
$$
\left( m, (n_i) \right) \mapsto (m \otimes n_i)_i.
$$

On [this page (proof of Lemma 8.12)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Commutative_Algebra/Direct_products,_direct_sums_and_the_tensor_product), it is said that this map is obviously surjective. But this is far from being obvious to me.
An arbitrary element of $\bigoplus_{i \in I} (M \otimes N_i)$ has the form $(m_i \otimes n_i)_i$ and not $(m \otimes n_i)_i$ as one might think. This makes it more difficult to find an element of $M \otimes \left( \bigoplus_{i \in I} N_i \right)$ which maps to that element.

Could you please explain this "obvious" observation to me? Thank you!

Comment: How about the element $\sum_{i\in I} m_i \otimes (\delta_{i,0} n_i)_i$?

Comment: Direct sum involves only finite sums, so surjectivity is easy.

Comment: LHS and RHS are modules. There is canonical map $M\times \oplus_iN_i\to \oplus_i(M\otimes N_i)$ as defined by your map. Note that image is a module. It suffices to check every $M\otimes N_i$ is contained in the image as every element of $\oplus_i(M\otimes N_i)$ is finite sum as Mohan above pointed out. Then it is obvious that every $m\otimes n_i\in M\otimes N_i$ has preimage $(m,n_i)$. Furthermore, one can have preimage of any linear combination in $M\otimes N_i$ by module morphism $M\times \oplus N_i\to\oplus_i(M\otimes N_i)$.